# Correct way to utilize p and util namespace in Spring XML Configuration

Tags: java, xml, spring

My goal is to rewrite the sessionFactory section of my xml file into the same format as all other areas in my xml file. I need to use the p-namespace to make things look consistent and neat. The problem that I ran into is using the util/p namespace.

Thank you for letting me edit this post. This is my entire xml file:

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p"
xmlns:jee="http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee"
xmlns:aop="http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop"
xmlns:util="http://www.springframework.org/schema/util"

xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-2.5.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee/spring-jee-2.5.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop/spring-aop-2.0.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-2.0.xsd">

<!-- DataSource Beans -->
<bean id="dataSource" class="org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource" 
    destroy-method="close"
    p:url="jdbc:hsqldb:file:database.dat;shutdown=true"
    p:driverClassName="org.hsqldb.jdbcDriver"
    p:username="sa"
    p:password="" />

<bean id="sessionFactory" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.LocalSessionFactoryBean">
    <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
    <property name="mappingResources">
        <list>
            <value>/com/bookstore/domain/Book.hbm.xml</value>
        </list>
    </property>
    <property name="hibernateProperties">
        <props>
            <prop key="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.HSQLDialect</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">update</prop>
        </props>
    </property>
</bean>

<!-- Template Beans -->
<bean id="jdbcTemplate" class="org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate"
    p:dataSource-ref="dataSource" />

<bean id="hibernateTemplate" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateTemplate"
    p:sessionFactory-ref="sessionFactory" />


<!-- DAO Beans -->
<bean id="bookDao" class="com.bookstore.data.BookDao"
    p:hibernateTemplate-ref="hibernateTemplate" />

<bean id="accountDao" class="com.bookstore.data.AccountDao"
    init-method="createTable"
    p:jdbcTemplate-ref="jdbcTemplate" />


<!-- Service Beans -->
<bean id="bookService" class="com.bookstore.services.BookService" 
    p:bookDao-ref="bookDao" />

<bean id="purchasingService" class="com.bookstore.services.PurchasingService"
    p:bookServiceInterface-ref="bookService" 
    p:accountServiceInterface-ref="accountService" ></bean>

<bean id="accountService" class="com.bookstore.services.AccountService"
    p:accountDao-ref="accountDao" />


<!-- AOP Advice Beans -->
<bean id="loggingAdvice" class="com.bookstore.advice.LoggingAdvice" />

<bean id="performanceTimingAdvice" class="com.bookstore.advice.PerformanceTimingAdvice" />

<!-- Auto Proxy -->
<aop:aspectj-autoproxy />

 </beans>
```

This is what I have so far - using a combination of util:list and util:properties:

```
<util:list id="mappingResourcesList">
    <value>/com/bookstore/domain/Book.hbm.xml</value>
</util:list>

<util:properties id="hibernatePropertiesProps">
    <prop key="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.HSQLDialect</prop>
    <prop key="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">update</prop>
</util:properties>

<bean id="sessionFactory" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.LocalSessionFactoryBean"
    p:dataSource-ref="dataSource"
    p:mappingResources-ref="mappingResourcesList"
    p:hibernateProperties-ref="hibernatePropertiesProps" />
```

The error message that I'm getting currently pertains to the util:list, but I'm equally suspicious of my util:properties as well:

```
Exception in thread "main" org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionStoreException: 
Line 22 in XML document from class path resource [application.xml] is invalid; 
nested exception is org.xml.sax.SAXParseException: cvc-complex-type.2.4.c: 
The matching wildcard is strict, but no declaration can be found for element 'util:list'.
```

What part of my util:list and util:properties must I change to get this to work?

Answer (score 39, accepted):

What XML namespaces do `p` and `util` map to?  These need to be declared with `xmlns:p="..."` and `xmlns:util="..."` somewhere within the XML element or a parent element of which they are being used.

(The error you're receiving is not specific to SAX, but is generic to XML parsing.)

For example, for using `util`, your XML should begin with the following:

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xmlns:util="http://www.springframework.org/schema/util"
       xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd http://www.springframework.org/schema/util http://www.springframework.org/schema/util/spring-util-3.0.xsd">
```

Additional details are available at http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/spring-framework-reference/html/xsd-config.html#xsd-config-body-schemas-util.

For `p`, you'd also want to add:

```
xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p"
```

Note that nothing requires you to use `p:` and `util:`.  These are simply being used by convention.  You could rewrite your XML to use `a:` and `b:` everywhere - as long as they are defined to map to the same XML namespaces.  (This is why they need to be defined.)

Comment: <beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p"
    xmlns:jee="http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee"
    xmlns:aop="http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop"
    xmlns:util="http://www.springframework.org/schema/util"

Comment: I have all the schema/declarations on top. Based on my readings of the documentation on spring source, this was to the best of my ability, and things don't seem to add up.

Comment: @user1079776 - please edit your question to include the complete XML file.

Comment: I included the entire XML file. But taking a look at the documentation all over again, I can't help but feel discouraged about my choice to use the p-namespace. Are there times when using the p-namespace is a bad choice for setting properties? Especially the ones that require the use of lists and props and so on...

Comment: You can read about the p-namespace and how it's used here: http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.2.x/spring-framework-reference/html/beans.html#beans-p-namespace

Answer (score 2):

You have following entries missing in xsi:schemaLocation:
http://www.springframework.org/schema/util http://www.springframework.org/schema/util/spring-util.xsd

Put them in your XML and you should be good.

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/10480017)

Comment: @VirajNalawade I don't think he's saying to follow the link; I think he's actually saying that the OP needs to paste that url in a specific location in the xml file ("...in xsi:schemaLocation..,", which is an attribute in the first xml tag in OP's code). While the answer is terse and maybe could be written to be a tad more clear, a link-only answer this is not.

Comment: @DennisMeng thats right.. What I thought atleast adding more description about tags with the link would have better..

Comment: ziesemer's answer has already addressed this. Your answer does not contribute anything new 4 years later.