# Error with xmlns:p in Spring

Tags: java, spring, javabeans

I need to add p: tag in Spring configuration file:

```
<beans
....
       xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p"
....>
```

but http://www.springframework.org/schema/p is 404.

What's wrong?

Comment: the XML Namespaces do not refer to URLs, their purpose is to give them unique identifiers (like URIs) and there is no need for a resource to be present at the apparent location the namespace seems to refer to. Depending on the XML parser and programming language or framework a parser _may_ look for XSD files for validation at the given location and apply them if present.

Comment: Probably relates  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8867444/correct-way-to-utilize-p-and-util-namespace-in-spring-xml-configuration

Comment: Ok, but I wrote question becouse InteliJ have written "URI is not registered" on the part of code above. I cannot find solution

Answer (score 0):

Under the namespaces there is not necessarily the XSD to be found. Most likely the addressed XML Schema is packages with spring