# Simbol p: in sentences Hibernate with spring

Tags: hibernate

Sorry, I would like know In this piece of code what's p: means simbol inside the sentence

```
<!-- DataSource -->
<bean id="dataSource" class="org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource" destroy-method="close"
    p:driverClassName="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver" 
    p:url="jdbc:mysql://localhost/dbname"
    p:username="root"
    p:password="password"/>
```

Comment: p is a xml namespace

Comment: The `p` namespace prefix (to which the `http://www.springframework.org/schema/p` namespace is customarily bound) allows for a shorthand bean property definition syntax. See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8867444/correct-way-to-utilize-p-and-util-namespace-in-spring-xml-configuration/8867467) or [here](https://www.concretepage.com/spring/example_p_namespace_spring) for more detailed explanations

Comment: Thank you very much for your help. It has been a great help to me